# How to display a string array in popupWindow in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, popupwindow

I'm having trouble with adding a string array to a popup Window. 
What I want is to get one random item from my array displayed on the popup.

I believe my `ArrayAdapter` is correct, but I can't figure out how to place `setAdapter`. 
How do I go about setting this up? 
I want the random array item to be displayed in the `TextView` id: `txtViewArrayContent`

I am new to Android, so please let me know if I'm going about this in the correct way. The java/xml files are below - thank you for looking!

Main Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnClosePopup;
    Button btnCreatePopup;
    String[] mAnimals;
    String randomStr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createArray();

        btnCreatePopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnCreatePopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                customPopupWindow();
            }
        });
    }
    private void createArray() {

        Resources res = getResources();
        mAnimals = res.getStringArray(R.array.animalArray);
        randomStr = mAnimals[new Random().nextInt(mAnimals.length)];
    }

    private PopupWindow popupWin;

    private void customPopupWindow(){

        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup,
                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            popupWin = new PopupWindow(layout, 600, 600, true);
            popupWin.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.screen_popup, Integer.parseInt(randomStr));
            // Set Adapter?

            btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private View.OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWin.dismiss();
        }
    };
}
```

Array xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="animalArray">
        <item>Cow</item>
        <item>Pig</item>
        <item>Bird</item>
        <item>Sheep</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Popup Window Layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_element"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff7c3f48"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:text="Title Goes Here"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewArrayContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:text="Content Goes Here" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I briefly checked your code - you are not calling anywhere:

```
createArray()
```

so I'm not surprised, that it is not working. Depending on what you want to achieve - call it in onCreate, or as first call inside onClickListener -> onClick.

**UPDATE:** Finally I compiled your code. As I wrote - you have to include createArray() in clickListener, and you wrote, that you did it. This, what you did wrongly is messing anything with ArrayAdapter. Replace ArrayAdaper line byt this:

```
((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtViewArrayContent)).setText(randomStr);
```

And it will be working.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I forgot i removed. In both instances it crashes the app. In onCreate the crash is immediate; in onClick it crashes when button is clicked.  FATAL EXCEPTION: main           at com.example.testarray_02.MainActivity.createArray(MainActivity.java:55)
            at com.example.testarray_02.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)

Comment: Weird - I compiled and an createArray and nothing - it is just working (also, during lookign in code I have not spotted anything, why this code could generate exception)

Comment: Hhmmm... So you are getting the array item in pop up?  I didn't think the `ArrayAdapter` would work without `setAdapter`.  I did update the main java, is there anything different to what you did now?

Comment: No, I just said, that I don't have fatal expception in createArray method (that is weird, that you have)

Comment: Solved the Exception Error. My array.xml file was not defined correctly in Values folder. (found through [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843131/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-array-resource-id-0x7f0?answertab=active#tab-top) ). It is not failing now. But still looking for help on how to display the array in popup :)