# Navigation Drawer android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException 4.X error

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

My Navigation Drawer a part of this

> And in Android 4.X **actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();** error , but Android 5.X not have this error...

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

and this my error logcat

```
04-12 13:45:08.037 22518-22518/com.example.yi.flinkservice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yi.flinkservice/com.example.yi.flinkservice.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070053
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2098)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070053
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
                                                                                 at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:283)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(Toolbar.java:718)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.setActionBarDescription(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:642)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$ToolbarCompatDelegate.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:634)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.setActionBarUpIndicator(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:457)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:246)
                                                                                 at com.example.yi.flinkservice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:230)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2098) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks to Help !

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843131/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-array-resource-id-0x7f0

Comment: Thanks you !!!  It's been repaired  !!!!  Very grateful  !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not a error of actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState(); method but when you call this, the string which you set is not found please check your string is available in both value folder value and value-21 and not then set in both.

Comment: Thanks I know it today , next time I will careful this probleam , Thanks you so much